# dsPIC30F: 10-bit ADC DONE bit vs the ADIF bit (interrupt request)

Tags: pic, adc

The ADC module has 2 very similar signals. The `DONE` bit in the `ADCON1` register and the interrupt request bit from the ADC. For some reasons samples in the documentation poll the `ADIF` bit and not the `DONE` bit.

Is there any difference in how these signals are raised? The difference in how they are cleared is clear. Please, do not comment on this.

Are there any pro/cons on what signal to poll from the software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want a comment:

For me the two bits work really similar. So I use the `DONE` bit when I work with polling and the interrupt request bit when I work with interrupts. For me it's the most clear way in the program flow but I didn't see other pro/cons.

Comment: No comments on **clearing** the two flags.